# Return reference to Linkedlist element

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to implement a function which instantiates a new element, adds it to a linked list and then returns the reference to the element it just created. This is what I came up with:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

struct Bar {
    ll: LinkedList<Foo>
}

struct Foo {}


impl Bar {
    fn foo_alloc<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &Option<&'a mut Foo> {
        let foo = Foo{};
        self.ll.push_back(foo);
        &self.ll.front_mut()
    }
}
```

I thought that when I bind the lifetime of the returned reference to the `Bar` instance (via `&'a mut self`) then this should be enough, but apparently it is not.

Here's the error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:10
   |
14 |         &self.ll.front_mut()
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
15 |     }
   |     - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 11:59...
  --> src/main.rs:11:60
   |
11 |       fn foo_alloc<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &Option<&'a mut Foo> {
   |  ____________________________________________________________^ starting here...
12 | |         let foo = Foo{};
13 | |         self.ll.push_back(foo);
14 | |         &self.ll.front_mut()
15 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the reference inside the `Option`, it's the `Option` object itself. Return it by value, not by reference.

```
impl Bar {
    fn foo_alloc(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Foo> {
        let foo = Foo{};
        self.ll.push_back(foo);
        self.ll.front_mut()
    }
}
```

I've also removed the lifetime annotations, because the default lifetime deduction does the correct thing here.

Comment: Yes, that solves it. Is it correct to say that `self.ll.front_mut()` creates an `Option` on the stack and the `&` before it tries to return the reference to the Option which of course is not living long enough as it's dropped at the end of the method?

Comment: Yes, the returned Option is a temporary, so you can't return a reference.